# Array with manual values

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I have an array where I will loop array values and I will also insert a manual value for every array value except before first value and after last value. If there i only one value in the array I will not insert this manual value. I have made a simplified example below.

The array is dynamic so there could be unlimited items.

```
for x=lbound(arrvalue) to ubound(arrvalue)
  ArrayValue1
    (Manual value)
  ArrayValue2
    (manual value)
  ArrayValue3

  ... and the array will go on like this

Next
```

When there is only one item in the array there I will not insert this manual value.

```
for x=lbound(arrvalue) to ubound(arrvalue)
  ArrayValue1
Next
```

Comment: What is your question/ problem?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear? I have no problem looping an array but i do not know how to insert this (manual value) IF the array has more than one value. If the array has only one value I will not insert this (manual value)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you displaying values, or are you trying to to "insert" values into the middle of an array, or what? If you're trying to add delimiters, do you know about `Join()` and `Split()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an internal array lbound is always 0 so you could use the code below.

`addManual` will create a separate result array that is capable of containing the additional elements. If you only need to output the values, you could use the `outputOnlyOption`.

```vbs
dim input
dim manual : manual = "manual element"

sub init
  redim input(3)
  input(0) = "element 0"
  input(1) = "element 1"
  input(2) = "element 2"
  input(3) = "element 3"
end sub

sub addManual
  dim res
  dim index

  if ubound(input) = 0 then
    res = input
  else
    redim res (ubound(input) * 2)

    for index = 0 to ubound(input)
      res(index * 2) = input( index)
      if index <> ubound(input) then
        res( index * 2 + 1) = manual
      end if
    next
  end if

  'print all elements
  for index = 0 to ubound(res)
    Response.Write( res( index) & "<br />")
  next
end sub


sub outputOnlyOption
  dim index
  for index = 0 to ubound(input)
    Response.Write( input( index) & "<br />")
    if index <> ubound(input) then
      ' print manual element
      Response.Write( manual & "<br />")
    end if
  next
end sub


call init
call addManual
call outputOnlyOption
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. But if the number of inputs `redim input(X)` is unknown?

Comment: this would depend on where you get your input values from. Maybe this should be a separate question?

Comment: The inputs are from a dynamic array that could range from 1 to "infinity", thats why I used Lbound to Ubound, to loop through the whole array. So the  `sub init` gives the value of four static values, I need this to be collected from a dynamic array.

Comment: You would not need to use the sub init. This is just to give you an example. you would use either of the other subs depending on what you want to achieve and replate the input variable with whatever you use as the array in your code. Without having your code and knowing exactly what you want to achieve, this is the best I can do for you.